# lib/lib.d.ts error Cannot find name 'object'

Tags: angular, typescript

Any one can help,I have checked so many times, actually it's working in different system but not in my system.

Package.json

```
{

      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~7.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~3.1.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~3.2.1"
      }
    }
```

Code with error:

```
export class CityModel {
    name: string = '';

    constructor(values: Object) {
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```

[here I am getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI5Zp.png)

Comment: on one have answer of this question. @Fenton

Comment: I think it is because nobody has managed to recreate it - it, rather famouly, "works on my machine".